# Problem with line 481 on my program and it is saying syntax error but the syntax seems fine

Tags: python

I am new to python programming. I have had a couple of courses online and I believe I have a basic knowledge to it. I decided to have a go in making an extremely easy program which basically asks a couple of questions and in the end prints the answer after it makes a few calculations based on the input I have previously input.

It was running fine until one day I ran into a problem which makes no sense to me because it prints out the error Invalid syntax but I know the syntax is right because I have about at least 50 print line above this one that are working just fine.

```
File "/home/garyhost/Hacking/Python_Programing/Program_1_All_In_One/All_In_One.py", line 241
    print("PiP Profit: ", take_profit_pip_calulation(num7, num5, num4))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My github project where the code is upload is as below:

https://github.com/GaryHOST893/all_in_one/

The problem starts on line 481 and below...the program, if it even can be called so, is extremely simple...

Comment: You're missing a close-parentheses on the line above. This is usually the cause of errors like this, when nothing seems wrong with the line in question.

Answer (score 2):

When the ^ symbol is shown at the start of the next line it means the line before has an error, as in this case it is not closed.

Reading your script, you have forgotten to add an `)` at the previous line.

So change
`print("Potential Profit: ", potential_profit_or_loss(num7, num5, long_short_calculation(risk_calculation(num1, num2, num5, num6)), " £/$/€")`

To:
`print("Potential Profit: ", potential_profit_or_loss(num7, num5, long_short_calculation(risk_calculation(num1, num2, num5, num6))), " £/$/€")`

Specifically this part num6))**)**, a 3rd one i've added.

I would recommend a better IDE like pyCharm which detects such minor mistakes.